# Second summernote returns null in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, summernote

I'm trying to use two summernotes in the same laravel form but the value of the seconnd one returns null. It works with php but not laravel

Here's my code

```
<textarea class="js-summernote" id="summernote" name="details"></textarea> 

<textarea class="js-summernote" id="summernote" name="content"></textarea>


<!--script files -->
<script src="{{ asset('backend/js/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/js/core/jquery.appear.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/js/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        //Init page helpers (Summernote + CKEditor plugins)
        App.initHelpers(['summernote', 'appear']);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your error is having both textareas with the same id. Probably. Using JQuery you could do just `$('.js-summernote').summernote();`.

Comment: Tried it, it's still  not working

Comment: don't you have to have different IDs for each instances?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ideal solution to the problem but it works only if both summernotes belongs to the same form group. So just had simply to place both textareas in the same form group

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-12" for="example-text-input">Content</label>
    <!-- Summernote Container -->
    <textarea class="js-summernote"  name="content"></textarea>

    <label class="col-xs-12" for="example-text-input">More Description</label> 
    <!-- Summernote Container -->    
    <textarea class="js-summernote" name="more_description"></textarea>                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

Just now, I was check in my file and it's working properly

```
<textarea class="js-summernote" id="summernote" name="details"></textarea> 

<textarea class="js-summernote" id="summernote2" name="content"></textarea>

<script src="{{ asset('backend/js/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
        $('#summernote2').summernote();
    });
</script>
```